# CoreText: Get ligature glyph

Tags: macos, text, core-text

I am using CoreText `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters`to get glyphs that correspond to unicode chars , i.e. `UniChar`. Now, I'd like to retrieve Ligature characters, for instance *fi*. Is there any way to retrieve ligature glyphs from CoreText (for instance by a series of unichars that should be combined)?

Thanks,
moka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some useful advice from the Core Text mailing list, here is the solution:

You can't get ligatures directly from CTFont, as no API exists to do that.

What you do instead is the following:

1. Use `CTLineCreateWithAttributedString()` to create a text line from the character sequence whose ligature you want to get.
2. Make sure to set `kCTLigatureAttributeName` to either 1 or 2 on the attributed string to get ligatures.
3. If done correctly, with a ligature that exists in the font, you should get a `CTLine` containing one `CTRun` containing one `CGGlyph` which will be the ligated glyph you are looking for!

If you don't want to go down this route, the only other way appears to be parsing the Open - / True Type font tables yourself which I don't recommend.

Hope that helps!